# ImageView and TextView disappears when switching between pages

Tags: textview, imageview

I'm a trainee. I want to ask you a question.
In the code I shared below, I switch to any page. Then I go back to the homepage with the back button. But when I switch to another page, whenever I press the back button, x and y disappear.Hello everyone. I'm a trainee. I want to ask you a question.can you help me with this?

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ImageView x;
TextView y;
ImageView LogOut;
RelativeLayout VallorantChatGrup,LolChatGrup,GTAchatgrup,CSGOchatGRUP;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    AGrup = findViewById(R.id.Agroup);
    x = findViewById(R.id.x);
    y = findViewById(R.id.y);
    String userName = getIntent().getStringExtra("userName");
    String ProfilePic = getIntent().getStringExtra("ProfilePic");
    y.setText(userName);
    Picasso.get().load(ProfilePic).into(x);
    LogOut = findViewById(R.id.logOut);
    BGrup =findViewById(R.id.Bgrup);
    Cgrup = findViewById(R.id.Cgrup);
    DRUP = findViewById(R.id.Dgrup);

    Agrup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            Intent intent =new Intent(MainActivity.this,AGrup.class );
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    Dgrup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            Intent intent =new Intent(MainActivity.this,DGrup.class );
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    BGrup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            Intent intent =new Intent(MainActivity.this,Bgroup.class );
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    CGrup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            finish();
            Intent intent =new Intent(MainActivity.this,CGrup.class );
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    LogOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
            Intent intent =new Intent(MainActivity.this,UygulamaGirisSayfasi.class );
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

}